# Teamviewer on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, mouse, teamviewer

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 with Teamviewer 15.15.5. I am unable to perform any operations on another desktop. I can see the desktop 100% but my mouse and keyboard do not function. I am trying to control a laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 on it. My daughter on Ubuntu 16.04 can control my desktop without problems, my mouse and keyboard have no effect on her desktop. I need to help set up a printer for her and I cannot do any operation. What should I do?

Comment: I have not used TeamViewer in a while. If I remember correctly, TeamViewer has a toggle to share (view) desktop versus control desktop. Make sure your daughter's TeamViewer is set to the correct setting.

Comment: A good place to start. https://www.teamviewer.com/en/support/ Not really a Ubuntu question.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly issues related to this can be solved easily by just reinstalling the application.
To reinstall: https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/